# Gradle SpringBoot 2.4.2 using bootBuildImage with tag

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

I am trying to use gradle SpringBoot plugin version 2.4.2 in a project and build a docker image using bootBuildImage  task.
when i try o build docker image with a tag that containes slash the build will fail because the slash is not allowed in the tag i guess.

Her is a snipt of the customized gradle bootBuildImage in my project gradle file:

```
bootBuildImage {
imageName = "hello-world:${art_contextUrl}/docker-repo"
publish = false
docker {
    publishRegistry {
        username = "${art_user}"
        password = "${art_password}"
        url = "${art_contextUrl}/docker-repo"
    }
}
```

}

The tag is consisted of context url of repository / repository.
But the task will fail. If i use simple tag lik 0.0.1 the task will complite and a docker image will be created.

How do I tag the image correctly without using docker tag command, i mean just taging from the bootBuildImage task

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/):

> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.

So no, you can't use slashes in a tag.

Comment: This is correct. If you try to use that tag with `docker tag` you will get an error like `is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format`. Spring Boot attempts to enforce Docker image name rules.